# Elasticsearch - retriving documents only, if multiple match by specific field

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an index in Elasticsearch with users' posts. I want to retrieve user_id from this index, if for given date range, there are at least X posts. Otherwise to skip such posts.

Anyway I can achieve it in ES or I have to get all entities and handle them later?

Trawa ;)

Comment: Please add you mapping and some documents for example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question I'll assume you have the fields `user` and `datetime` in your mapping.

You can get the requested data like so:

Get the list of users who have more then X (i.e X=100) posts by given date range -  aggregate by user name for specific date range:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "range": {
            "datetime": {
              "gte": "2017-05-01",
              "lt": "2017-06-01"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "users": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "user",
        "min_doc_count": 100
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Edit the query to match your date range (and its format) and `min_doc_count` to the minimum X posts per user.

**EDIT**:

There is no way to avoid `terms_aggregation` to get all distinct values.
50k values do seems to be to much data to retrieve - **but it also depends on your cluster**.
My suggestion is to add another filter, lets say, alphabetically filter so instead of getting 50k results at once you can do it in other several queries:

```
"must": [
        {
          "range": {
            "datetime": {
              "gte": "2017-05-01",
              "lt": "2017-06-01"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "wildcard": {
            "user": "a*"
          }
        },
        {
          "wildcard": {
            "user": "b*"
          }
        }
      ]
```

See [Wildcard](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-wildcard-query.html)

Unfortunately, scrolling on aggregation results is not available. Manually dividing the data to pieces is the best thing I can see right now.

Comment: Thanks for help, I got to the same query with aggregations. The thing is, that I need only user_ids, so stage 1 is enough. I was wondering only, how it will manage on really big data (I want to run it on indices of 50k users and over 200k posts). Won't it have problems with performance? I assume I will have to figure out a way to get aggregation results with scroll.